# How to display only one answer at a time using expandable recyclerview on andorid

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

Here i have attached the source code for recycler expandale view. The output for this project is while press question the answer has displayed. But here while press the second question the second question answer is also displayed without hide of fist question answer. My requirement is displayed only current action of question answer is enough. Kindly please help me to solve this problem.
I here by attached my code.

MainActivity

---

```
package com.anandbose.expandablelistdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        List<ExpandableListAdapter.Item> data = new ArrayList<>();

        ExpandableListAdapter.Item q1 = new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.HEADER, "What is Swift?");
        q1.invisibleChildren = new ArrayList<>();
        q1.invisibleChildren.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Swift is a mobile app designed to help you save money. By inputting your financial information, daily expenses, and income you can begin building your personal savings. Swift will automatically generate goals for you every week and reaching those goals will result in points, which can be redeemed for prizes"));


        ExpandableListAdapter.Item q2 = new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.HEADER, "Where is Swift located?");
        q2.invisibleChildren = new ArrayList<>();
        q2.invisibleChildren.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Swift is based in the United States of America and in the United Kingdom but users anywhere in the world can use the app.\n"));


        data.add(q1);
        data.add(q2);

        recyclerview.setAdapter(new ExpandableListAdapter(data));
    }
}
```

ExpandableListAdapter

---

```
package com.anandbose.expandablelistdemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by anandbose on 09/06/15.
 */
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    public static final int HEADER = 0;
    public static final int CHILD  = 1;
    ArrayList<String> header = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<Item> data;
    List<String> child1;
    // Hash map for both header and child
    HashMap<String, List<String>> hashMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    public ExpandableListAdapter(List<Item> data) {
        this.data = data;
        Log.e("data constructor", "data constructor" + data);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int type) {
        View view = null;
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        float dp = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int subItemPaddingLeft = (int) (18 * dp);
        int subItemPaddingTopAndBottom = (int) (5 * dp);
        switch (type) {
            case HEADER:
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, parent, false);
                ListHeaderViewHolder header = new ListHeaderViewHolder(view);
                return header;
            case CHILD:
                TextView itemTextView = new TextView(context);
                itemTextView.setPadding(subItemPaddingLeft, subItemPaddingTopAndBottom, 0, subItemPaddingTopAndBottom);
                itemTextView.setTextColor(0x88000000);
                itemTextView.setLayoutParams(
                        new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                return new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemTextView) {
                };
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Item item = data.get(position);
        Log.e("item", "item" + item);
        switch (item.type) {
            case HEADER:
                final ListHeaderViewHolder itemController = (ListHeaderViewHolder) holder;
                itemController.refferalItem = item;
                Log.e("refferalItem", "refferalItem" + itemController.refferalItem.toString());
                itemController.header_title.setText(item.text);
                if (item.invisibleChildren == null) {

                    itemController.btn_expand_toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_minus);

                } else {
                    itemController.btn_expand_toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_plus);
                }
                itemController.header_title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (item.invisibleChildren == null) {
                            item.invisibleChildren = new ArrayList<Item>();
                            int count = 0;
                            int pos = data.indexOf(itemController.refferalItem);
                            Log.e("pos", "pos" + pos);
                            int index = pos + 1;
                            Log.e("data.size()", "data.size()" + data.size());
                            while (data.size() > pos + 1 && data.get(pos + 1).type == CHILD) {

                                Log.e("while", "while-->" + pos + 1);
                                Log.e("CHILD", "CHILD-->" + CHILD);
                                Log.e("datatype", "datatype--->" + data.get(pos + 1).type);
                                item.invisibleChildren.add(data.remove(pos + 1));
                                count++;

                            }
                            notifyItemRangeRemoved(pos + 1, count);
                            itemController.btn_expand_toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_plus);
                        }

                        else {
                            int pos = data.indexOf(itemController.refferalItem);
                            for (int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
                                if(data.get(i).type==CHILD){
                                    int index = pos + 1;
                                    for (Item j : item.invisibleChildren) {
                                        data.remove(j);
                                        index++;
                                    }

                                }
                                else{
                                    Log.e("else 1 ","pos "+i +" "+data.get(i).type);
                                }
                            }
                            Log.e("data.size() else", "data.size()" + data.size());
                            Log.e("pos ele", "pos else" + pos);
                            int index = pos + 1;
                            for (Item i : item.invisibleChildren) {
                                data.add(index, i);
                                index++;
                            }
                            notifyItemRangeInserted(pos + 1, index - pos - 1);
                            itemController.btn_expand_toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_minus);
                            item.invisibleChildren = null;
                        }
                    }
                });
                break;
            case CHILD:
                TextView itemTextView = (TextView) holder.itemView;
                itemTextView.setText(data.get(position).text);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return data.get(position).type;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    private static class ListHeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView  header_title;
        public ImageView btn_expand_toggle;
        public Item      refferalItem;

        public ListHeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            header_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.header_title);
            btn_expand_toggle = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_expand_toggle);
        }
    }

    public static class Item {
        public int        type;
        public String     text;
        public List<Item> invisibleChildren;

        public Item() {

        }

        public Item(int type, String text) {
            this.type = type;
            this.text = text;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_header

---

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
    android:paddingStart="13dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_title"
        android:textColor="@color/app_blue"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_expand_toggle"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_plus"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>
</LinearLayout>
```